# What is wrong with this MongoDB Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my sample document.I have many such documents where `Cpe.Srno` is a key and `Cpe.date` keeps getting updated using an Api

```
{
    "_id": "8NH5rNCz47fyoo3z2",
    "Cpe": {
        "Srno": "GZDBDt2NmpMv54j",
        "date": { 
            "$date": "2016-12-04T14:51:26.452Z" 
        }
    },
    "serialNumber": 4.703961341e+09,
    "Device": {
        "object_id": 1,
        "terminal_id": 3,
        "Info": { 
            "FirmwareVersion": { 
                "value": "5.9.2"
            },
            "Model": {
                "value": "lunus    Rustic HRK   paxton -  989"
            },
            "DeviceSerialNumber": {
               "value": 3.830919496e+09
            },
            "BatteryType": {
               "value": "Handcrafted  lithium  battery"
            },
            "SavedPriority": { 
                "value": 7 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to group by `Cpe.Srno` and get the latest document using `Cpe.date`.So i get distinct `Cpe.Srno` and only the latest documents.

I am stuck at the group stage.This is my code

```
db.AllDevices.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "Cpe.date": -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Cpe.Srno",
            "latest": { $first: "$Cpe.date" }
        }
    },
])
```

and this is my result

```
{ "_id" : "qst3pnS3EQi8uHb", "latest" : ISODate("2016-12-04T14:51:26.487Z") }
{ "_id" : "Ur45SS1I3Yaji2p", "latest" : ISODate("2016-12-04T14:51:26.513Z") }
{ "_id" : "9ZZXVVEAQ5pA9Ax", "latest" : ISODate("2016-12-04T14:51:26.518Z") }
```

I need to get the whole data,all the fields(I only get two fields).I checked out $push ,`$addToSet`.They don't seem to work for me.
Where am I going wrong or am I missing something.

Tried `$match` after `$group`

```
db.AllDevices.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "Cpe.date": -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Cpe.Srno",
            "latest": { $first: "$Cpe.date" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Srno: "$_id",
            datetag: "$latest",
            _id: 0
        }
    },
    { $match: { "Cpe.Srno": "$Srno", "Cpe.date": "$datetag" } }
])
```

Doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of ***[$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/aggregation-variables/)*** to push the whole document followed by project with ***[$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)*** to pick the latest.

```
aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "Cpe.date": -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Cpe.Srno",
        "fields": {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "latest": {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$fields", 0]
        }
    }
}])
```